# GetCurrentLocation is working on Cordova/PhoneGap App even when the Location services are turned off in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

GetCurrentLocation is working on Cordova/PhoneGap App even when the Location services are turned off in Android 4.4.2.

Cordova Version is 2.9

Device is Nexus4 V4.4.2

Code :

```
var onSuccess = function() {
    alert("success")
}
var onError = function() {
    alert("error")
}
var options = {
    maximumAge: 0,
    timeout: 60000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Code is working fine in previous android versions.
But in Android 4.4.2 it alerts success even if the location services are turned off.

Unable to find a solution, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please Update your Cordova Version

Comment: Hi Immi, Version 3.0 was a major update, will require much code changes and I dont have that much time

Comment: Did you try to alert success coordinates? If they are undefined,  simply check for it and treat it as error.

Comment: @Regent they are not undefined

Comment: Do they show correct values? If so, maybe you should restart phone after changing Location services' settings

Comment: Restarting the phone solves the problem(only if location services are off at the restart) but it is not a solution for a App using current location.

Comment: I have the same problem. Even phone restart is also not helping me. Any advice ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cordova V2.9 there was a bug related to current location mentioned here : [GetCurrentLocation is working on Cordova/PhoneGap App even when the Location services are turned off in Android 4.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778667/getcurrentlocation-is-working-on-cordova-phonegap-app-even-when-the-location-ser)

As Cordova use the default browser's Geolocation implementation, it was a WebView bug mentioned here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6548

As a workaround this plugin use Android API to check the status of the Location Services.

Plugin : https://github.com/mandeeppasbola/Cordova-Plugins/tree/master/Location%20Service%20Status